# foreach within for each (preg match url, and imgurl)

Tags: php, foreach

I have html in a variable ($data) and find the URL, which I call `$url` and the `imgurl`,

but I can't figure out how to also find URL for each item (it ends up echoing all matches not per each).

I m trying to learn the solution in general , lets say you have a html page you want to extract img src and href src and echo all of them for each...

```
$data = "75http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7a/Britney_Spears_2013.jpg\46imgrefurl\75http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Britney_Spears\?imgurl\75http://www.spirituelquotes.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/britney-spears.jpg\46imgrefurl\75http://www.spirituelquotes.com/celebrities/britney-spears/";


//finds url; (below is code rough to give an idea ) 
 preg_match_all("/ru=\'(.*?)\'\;/is", $data, $matches); 
matches = $url;

 //finds imgurl
 preg_match_all("/imgurl%5C75(.*?)%5C/is", $data, $matches); 

 matches = $img;

 foreach $maches(){
 echo $url $img;  
 //whatever else you want to do
 }


output would be:

http://www.example.com http://www.example.com/image.jpg

http://www.example.com/dir/name2 http://www.example.com/image2.jpg

http://www.example.com/dir/name3 http://www.example.com/image3.jpg

http://www.example.com/dir/name3 http://www.example.com/image4.jpg
```

or:

```
$data = getfile contents(http://example.com)  

//finds url;
preg_match_all("/ru=\'(.*?)\'\;/is", $data, $matches); 
matches = $url

//finds the img url
 preg_match_all("/imgurl%5C75(.*?)%5C/is", $data, $matches); 

foreach($matches[1] as $imgurl){
 echo $imgurl $url and (basically want to echo url for each matches in foreach command)


 }
```

this code works but I just want to add the url within the for each:

```
preg_match_all("/ru=\'(.*?)\'\;/is", $data, $matches); 
foreach($matches[1] as $url)


preg_match_all("/imgurl%5C75(.*?)%5C/is", $data, $matches); 
foreach($matches[1] as $imgurl){
$filename = basename($imgurl);

    echo $imgurl; //works
    echo $url; //displays all $urls found

$img = "$filename";

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$ch = curl_init(); 
$timeout = 0; 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $imgurl); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1); 

$image = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 

$f = fopen($img, 'w');
fwrite($f, $image);
fclose($f);


}

}
}
```

Comment: Is this php file working or throwing some error. See  the line after first preg_match  matches

Comment: Your pseudo code is not clear enough. Since we do not know the html code you try to parse, there is no way to help you out.

Comment: I m trying to learn the tecneq in general , lets say you have a html page you want to extract img src and href src and echo all of them for each...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to parse something complicated like HTML with regular expressions is always a bad idea. You should use a parser for such a job.

```
<?php

// Suppress errors on unknown elements.
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

// Create a new libxml2 DOM document instance.
$domDocument = new \DOMDocument();

// Parse the HTML string.
$domDocument->loadHTML("<a href=http://www.example.com/dir/name><img src=http://www.example.com/image.jpg></a><a href=http://www.example.com/dir/name2><img src=http://www.example.com/image2.jpg></a><a href=http://www.example.com/dir/name3><img src=http://www.example.com/image3.jpg></a><a href=http://www.example.com/dir/name4><img src=http://www.example.com/image4.jpg></a>");

// Go through all DOM elements we are interested in.
foreach (array("a" => "href", "img" => "src") as $tagName => $attribute) {
    foreach ($domDocument->getElementsByTagName($tagName) as $domElement) {
        // Make sure the element has the desired attribute.
        if ($domElement->hasAttribute($attribute)) {
            echo $domElement->getAttribute($attribute) , PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that libxml2 might throw errors if you try to parse an HTML5 document which contains some of the new elements. You can work around this problem by using [`libxml_use_internal_errors`](https://php.net/manual/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php).

---

If you insist on the usage of regular expressions or you simply want to learn regular expressions (check out [regx101.com](https://regex101.com/) [no affiliation] for learning regular expressions) then the solution would be:

```
<?php

$data = "<a href=http://www.example.com/dir/name><img src=http://www.example.com/image.jpg></a><a href=http://www.example.com/dir/name2><img src=http://www.example.com/image2.jpg></a><a href=http://www.example.com/dir/name3><img src=http://www.example.com/image3.jpg></a><a href=http://www.example.com/dir/name4><img src=http://www.example.com/image4.jpg></a>";

preg_match_all("/(?:href|src)=(?:\"|')?([^\"'> ]*)(?:\"|'| |>)/", $data, $matches);

var_dump($matches);

/* OUTPUT:
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(8) {
    [0]=>
    string(37) "href=http://www.example.com/dir/name>"
    [1]=>
    string(37) "src=http://www.example.com/image.jpg>"
    [2]=>
    string(38) "href=http://www.example.com/dir/name2>"
    [3]=>
    string(38) "src=http://www.example.com/image2.jpg>"
    [4]=>
    string(38) "href=http://www.example.com/dir/name3>"
    [5]=>
    string(38) "src=http://www.example.com/image3.jpg>"
    [6]=>
    string(38) "href=http://www.example.com/dir/name4>"
    [7]=>
    string(38) "src=http://www.example.com/image4.jpg>"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(8) {
    [0]=>
    string(31) "http://www.example.com/dir/name"
    [1]=>
    string(32) "http://www.example.com/image.jpg"
    [2]=>
    string(32) "http://www.example.com/dir/name2"
    [3]=>
    string(33) "http://www.example.com/image2.jpg"
    [4]=>
    string(32) "http://www.example.com/dir/name3"
    [5]=>
    string(33) "http://www.example.com/image3.jpg"
    [6]=>
    string(32) "http://www.example.com/dir/name4"
    [7]=>
    string(33) "http://www.example.com/image4.jpg"
  }
}
*/
```

Comment: thanks but I tried it but it doesn't support non standard tags...  imgurl\75http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7a/Britney_Spears_2013.jpg\46imgrefurl\75http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Britney_Spears\   imgurl\75http://img2-3.timeinc.net/people/i/2012/news/121001/britney-spears-2-300.jpg\46imgrefurl\75http://www.people.com/people/article/0,,20737254,00.html\

Comment: Have you read my complete answer? I stated that you may use `libxml_use_internal_errors` if you need to parse non-standard tags. I also extended my answer with a regular expression solution for you.

Comment: I did read that answer but my brain is so limited on learning just to get this far took 100 percent brain power  wanted to learn within.... but I googled libxml and it got more confusing sorry..  thank you fellow human on earth for helping

Comment: I added a code that works within 1 preg match all but not url

Comment: You won't be able to understand any solution if you don't understand the basics of PHP. Try to read a book or website on learning PHP or any other high-level programming language, it will help you a lot. My answer contains two perfect solutions that should work for you. I also added the usage of the `libxml_use_internal_errors` function for you.

Comment: The answer contains a single regular expression which extracts both `href` and `src`.

Comment: I agree with u but in my country im always limited with time at the internet café and power outs. soon I would know xml.  but I have ADHD its really hard to focus on anything

Comment: host blocks libxml and domdocument

Comment: But you surely can buy a book in your country. ;) Regular expressions are of course a valid last resort if you have no possibility to use a parser that is intended for the job.

Comment: u are right but after this  I willhave to go to full time job of cleaning gutters Ill forget everything I learn about computers. host block domdocument :(